# Cannot remove this sliding door

Tags: sliding-glass-door, stuck

I have a sliding door that I cannot remove. There's a roller that need to be cleaned or replaced. I believe I'm supposed to lower the rollers so it will tilt in or out. However, there isn't enough clearance at the top or the bottom to have enough room to tilt it out.

Is there something I'm missing?

Top:

[image]

Bottom:
[image]

Comment: I have never seen a sliding door with end grain wood filling a portion of the cut for the hardware. There is always a removable cover, usually.... Is the white curved piece flexible? As in, can it be pushed up to flatten it against the top jamb? Or is it removable, pulling it out of a groove it is set in? It also looks like the interior trim is covering the  wood retainer that may be removable, AFTER the trim is removed. If so, it can be leaned out from the top.

Comment: @Jack Yes, it is odd. I can't remove that wood on the bottom either. Those two notches are from my seeing if I could knock it out with a screw driver. That white piece is pretty solid, I don't think I'll be able to unscrew it, and slide it out. I'm also hoping I can do this without removing the trim, but not looking hopeful.

Comment: If it were me, I would start from the bottom and chip out the block a 1/4" or so at a time. They appear to be an afterthought,and glued in, so they will not simply tap out like you have tried. For that type of block to stay in place over all this time, would have to be glued in. But honestly I don't see how it will help remove the door after they are out. It may expose an adjustment screw at best. My best guess is that it will tip out from the top, after stuff is out the way.